# $A$ similar to $-A$ implies direct sum decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm working on linear algebra/Jordan form questions, studying out of Dummit and Foote.

Problem:  Let $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $P \in GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $AP = -PA$.  Show that $\mathbb{C}^{n} = V_{1} \oplus V_{2}$ where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are subspaces such that $AV_{1} \subset V_2$ and $AV_{2} \subset V_{1}$.

For doing this problem, I have made only a few observatios, but don't know how to proceed.  First, every linear transformation over a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space has a Jordan canonical form, so $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ has a Jordan basis.  If $\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k\}$ are the distinct eigenvalues, then $\mathbb{C}^{n} = E_{\lambda_1} \oplus ... \oplus E_{\lambda_k}$ where $E_{\lambda_i}$ is the generalized eigenspace for $\lambda_{i}$.

If $AP = -PA$, then $A$ is similar to $-A$, so they have the same Jordan canonical form (except possibly for conjugating by a permutation matrix).  In particular, the eigenvalues of $A$ is the same set as the eigenvalues of $-A$.  So if $w \ne 0$ is a generalized eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, we have $(A - \lambda I)^{k}w = 0$ for some $k \geq 1$.  Then $(-A + \lambda I)^{k}w = 0$, so $w$ is a generalized eigenvector of $-A$ with eigenvalue of $-\lambda$.  By similarity, $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, so there exists $v \ne 0$ linearly independent of the vectors in $E_{\lambda}$ such that $(A + \lambda I)^{l}v \ne 0$.  This says that each $E_{\lambda}$ has an independent $E_{-\lambda}$ in the eigendecomposition of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, whenever $\lambda \ne 0$.

I am inclined to say that the decomposition into $V_1$ and $V_2$ must be based on this separation into positive and negative eigenvalues, but $A$-invariance of the eigenspaces (i.e. $AE_{\lambda} \subset E_{\lambda}$ for any $\lambda$) makes me think this won't work.  I appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: You've made some great observations!  One thing concerns me: what if $\lambda = 0$?  In fact, from $P^{-1}AP = -A$, we have $\det(A) = (-1)^n \det(A)$, so $\det(A) = 0$ for $n$ odd.  So for $n$ odd, $0$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: I figured that if there was a nontrivial zero eigenspace, then I could lump it into either $V_1$ or $V_2$ without much impact.  Suppose $E_0$ is a component of $V_1$.  Then any $x \in E_0$ will have $Ax = 0 \in V_2$.  And $AV_2$ will belong to the part of $V_1$ that is separate from $E_0$ (which basically brings us back to the initial problem).

Comment: But I would have to argue this for nonproper eigenvectors for zero as well.  For that, I'm not sure.

Comment: @user55912 For a non trivial Young block corresponding to zero eigenvalue: suppose the basis elements of the eigenspace are $e_{i_1},e_{i_2},\ldots,e_{i_k}$ then $A$ does the following mappings $$ 0 \leftarrow e_{i_1} \leftarrow e_{i_2}\leftarrow \ldots \leftarrow e_{i_k} $$. We could then add the even $e_{i_r} $ to $V_1$ and the others to $V_2$.